# create hive table and find total NULL fields in each column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to write a query that returns number of null fields in every column in a hive table

eg:

```
col1|col2|col3
----------------
NULL|a   |b
NULL|a   |b
e   |NULL|f
```

the query should return 2 1 0 for the above table. Someone help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
sum(if(col1 is null, 1, 0)),
sum(if(col2 is null, 1, 0)),
sum(if(col3 is null, 1, 0))
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe K! Do you know of a way to do this when you have a really large number of columns that doesn't involve having to name every single column?